# GLM fails to compile with g++/C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, g++, glm-math

I'm trying to use [GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.7/index.html) for a game project, but when compiling with g++ and -std=c++11, I'm getting a lot of compile errors.

This is the code I'm trying to compile: (taken from [here](http://www.cis.gvsu.edu/~dulimarh/Okto/cis367/))

```
#include "glm/vec3.hpp"
#include "glm/gtx/io.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using glm::vec3;

int main () {
    vec3 i_am_zero;

    cout << i_am_zero << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My command line:

```
g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test.exe
```

The compiler output:

```
In file included from glm/gtx/../detail/func_trigonometric.hpp:205:0,
                 from glm/gtx/../trigonometric.hpp:35,
                 from glm/gtx/../glm.hpp:110,
                 from glm/gtx/io.hpp:50,
                 from glmtest.cpp:2:
glm/gtx/../detail/func_trigonometric.inl:166:14: error: 'std::asinh' has not been declared
   using std::asinh;
              ^
In file included from glm/gtx/../detail/func_trigonometric.hpp:205:0,
                 from glm/gtx/../trigonometric.hpp:35,
                 from glm/gtx/../glm.hpp:110,
                 from glm/gtx/io.hpp:50,
                 from glmtest.cpp:2:
glm/gtx/../detail/func_trigonometric.inl:185:14: error: 'std::acosh' has not been declared
   using std::acosh;
              ^
glm/gtx/../detail/func_trigonometric.inl:206:14: error: 'std::atanh' has not been declared
   using std::atanh;
              ^
In file included from glm/gtx/../detail/func_exponential.hpp:132:0,
                 from glm/gtx/../exponential.hpp:35,
                 from glm/gtx/../glm.hpp:111,
                 from glm/gtx/io.hpp:50,
                 from glmtest.cpp:2:
glm/gtx/../detail/func_exponential.inl:43:14: error: 'std::log2' has not been declared
   using std::log2;
              ^
In file included from glm/gtx/../detail/func_common.hpp:455:0,
                 from glm/gtx/../common.hpp:35,
                 from glm/gtx/../glm.hpp:112,
                 from glm/gtx/io.hpp:50,
                 from glmtest.cpp:2:
glm/gtx/../detail/func_common.inl:229:16: error: 'std::trunc' has not been declared
   using ::std::trunc;
                ^
glm/gtx/../detail/func_common.inl:248:16: error: 'std::round' has not been declared
   using ::std::round;
                ^
glm/gtx/../detail/func_common.inl: In instantiation of 'vecType<T, P> glm::round(const vecType<T, P>&) [with T = float; glm::precision P = (glm::precision)0u; vecType = glm::tvec2]':
glm/gtx/../detail/func_packing.inl:47:55:   required from here
glm/gtx/../detail/func_common.inl:262:59: error: no matching function for call to 'glm::detail::functor1<float, float, (glm::precision)0u, glm::tvec2>::call(<unresolved overloaded function type>, const glm::tvec2<float, (glm::precision)0u>&)'
   return detail::functor1<T, T, P, vecType>::call(round, x);
                                                           ^
glm/gtx/../detail/func_common.inl:262:59: note: candidate is:
In file included from glm/gtx/../detail/func_trigonometric.inl:33:0,
                 from glm/gtx/../detail/func_trigonometric.hpp:205,
                 from glm/gtx/../trigonometric.hpp:35,
                 from glm/gtx/../glm.hpp:110,
                 from glm/gtx/io.hpp:50,
                 from glmtest.cpp:2:
glm/gtx/../detail/_vectorize.hpp:58:41: note: static glm::tvec2<R, P> glm::detail::functor1<R, T, P, glm::tvec2>::call(R (*)(T), const glm::tvec2<T, P>&) [with R = float; T = float; glm::precision P = (glm::precision)0u]
   GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER static tvec2<R, P> call(R (*Func) (T x), tvec2<T, P> const & v)
                                         ^
glm/gtx/../detail/_vectorize.hpp:58:41: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'float (*)(float)'
In file included from glm/gtx/../detail/func_common.hpp:455:0,
                 from glm/gtx/../common.hpp:35,
                 from glm/gtx/../glm.hpp:112,
                 from glm/gtx/io.hpp:50,
                 from glmtest.cpp:2:
glm/gtx/../detail/func_common.inl: In instantiation of 'vecType<T, P> glm::round(const vecType<T, P>&) [with T = float; glm::precision P = (glm::precision)0u; vecType = glm::tvec4]':
glm/gtx/../detail/func_packing.inl:105:52:   required from here
glm/gtx/../detail/func_common.inl:262:59: error: no matching function for call to 'glm::detail::functor1<float, float, (glm::precision)0u, glm::tvec4>::call(<unresolved overloaded function type>, const glm::tvec4<float, (glm::precision)0u>&)'
   return detail::functor1<T, T, P, vecType>::call(round, x);
                                                           ^
glm/gtx/../detail/func_common.inl:262:59: note: candidate is:
In file included from glm/gtx/../detail/func_trigonometric.inl:33:0,
                 from glm/gtx/../detail/func_trigonometric.hpp:205,
                 from glm/gtx/../trigonometric.hpp:35,
                 from glm/gtx/../glm.hpp:110,
                 from glm/gtx/io.hpp:50,
                 from glmtest.cpp:2:
glm/gtx/../detail/_vectorize.hpp:76:41: note: static glm::tvec4<R, P> glm::detail::functor1<R, T, P, glm::tvec4>::call(R (*)(T), const glm::tvec4<T, P>&) [with R = float; T = float; glm::precision P = (glm::precision)0u]
   GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER static tvec4<R, P> call(R (*Func) (T x), tvec4<T, P> const & v)
                                         ^
glm/gtx/../detail/_vectorize.hpp:76:41: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'float (*)(float)'
```

It appears that it can't find some functions from cmath - but these errors still remain if I include cmath before I include glm.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that this is a bug with GLM version 0.9.7. Downgrading to 0.9.5 resolved the problem for me. It's being tracked as [issue 405](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/issues/405).

Comment: Can you link the issue here too?

Comment: Sure, give me a sec to write it up.

Answer (score 1):

This compiles and runs just fine with gcc 4.8.2 at c++11 standard on my machine.

I get a series of warnings

```
/usr/include/glm/gtc/quaternion.inl:639:165: note: #pragma message: GLM: rotate function taking degrees as a parameter is deprecated. #define GLM_FORCE_RADIANS before including GLM headers to remove this message.
```

But if I change the code to

```
#define GLM_FORCE_RADIANS
#include "glm/vec3.hpp"
#include "glm/gtx/io.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using glm::vec3;

int main () {
    vec3 i_am_zero;

    cout << i_am_zero << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

then it compiles fine with `-Wall -Werror`.

The glm header includes `cmath`, so including it again shouldn't change things for you.

I am using GLM version 0.9.5. You might want to upgrade your GLM version maybe and / or compiler version?

Comment: I am on GLM 0.9.7 and g++ 4.9.3. I'll give it a try with GLM 0.9.5.

Comment: Downgrading fixed the problem. I'll submit it as a bug on their GitHub. Thanks for the answer!